# Mac OS X Recovery Mode - Headless Access?

Tags: macos, ssh, recovery, screen-sharing

I have a Macbook Pro, which unfortunately the screen has died on. External displays do not work either.

I can normally ssh and screenshare into the mac fine, but now need to repair the internal HD. 
Is it possible to screen share or ssh into a machine in recovery mode? 
At the moment it doesn't seem to be appearing on the network, but I know recovery mode should connect to my wifi.

Is ssh enabled or can I enable it somehow?

Comment: The submitted answer is a great one, and absolutely solves the described problem in the description, but I'm still wondering if there's a solution to enabling SSH during recovery mode... I would contribute 50 rep (bounty) for an answer on how to enable SSH during recovery!

Answer (score 2):

Turn the problem upside down. Boot the laptop in target disk mode and use another (working) Mac to access the drive over firewire or thunderbolt. It will behave just like an external drive.